# Set the date and time in menubar to be in a specific format

Tags: macos, menu-bar

I want the menubar to display the date and time in the menubar as follows:

```
2012-10-03 09.12.14
```

which translates into Year-Month-Day 24hr.min.second

**What I've tried:**

Gone into System Preferences > Date & Time > Clock

Selected: Digital; Display time with seconds; use 24-hour clock

This gets me close to having the time right.

Gone into System Preferences > Date & Time > Date & Time > Open Language & Text > Formats > Dates > Customize

Changed every date format (short, medium, long, full) to have yyyy-MM-dd

Gone into System Preferences > Date & Time > Date & Time > Open Language & Text > Formats > Times > Customize

Change every time format to kk.mm.ss

**The problem:**

It still shows the date like:

```
3 Oct 13:19:12
```

in the menubar.

**Details:**

I am running Mac OS X 10.7.5

Any help or suggestions you can give, much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a free app called Day-O that is flexible and can do what is being asked:  https://shauninman.com/archive/2016/10/20/day_o_2_mac_menu_bar_clock

Answer (score 2):

Whilst I'm not sure this is possible with the built-in menubar clock formats, you can acheive the format you require using the excellent [iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) ($16, but it does have a 14-day free trial).

[image]

Comment: Well, that appears to do it, but I can't believe that the solution requires payment.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old thread but in case anyone else is looking for alternatives, I recommend [Itsycal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRnyI.jpg). Absolutely FREE and customisable date/time with calendar view options

[image: joined three screenshots of Itsycal]

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that OS X uses multiple Formats for Date and Time (depending on where it is shown) and you must modify the right one? E.G. the timestamp in Finder has a different format than in the top right corner.

Comment: Any idea which one? I've tried several combinations like the OP has and it only modifies the way the date/time is shown in the Finder, not the date/time displayed in the menubar

Comment: I've modified all of them to be identical to what I want. The problem remains.

Comment: mhm I even found this http://www.macyourself.com/2008/08/31/modify-the-default-clock-in-os-xs-menu-bar-to-show-the-full-date/ maybe it is a bug