# Hide month in menu bar in OS X

Tags: macos, menu-bar

On my MacBook Pro the date is shown like this:

[image: Menu Bar]

I'd like to remove the word 'Chaitra' from the menu bar ([Chaitra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitra) is a month of the Hindu calendar). How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set the date and time in menubar to be in a specific format](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66089/set-the-date-and-time-in-menubar-to-be-in-a-specific-format)

Answer (score 5):

To change the format of the date, you want to go to your "Language and Text" settings. Click on the "Region" tab at the top, then go to the section under "Dates":

[image: Dates section in Language and Texts settings]

Click on the "Customize..." button, then you should see a whole drag and drop section where you can change how the date is displayed:

[image: Customize Date]

Answer (score 3):

Go to **System Preferences** → **Date & Time** → **Clock** and uncheck **Show Date**.

[image: Screenshot]

To change the language used, go to **System Preferences** → **Language & Region** → **Advanced** and set **Format Language** to the language you want to use.

Comment: brother i want date and time what i don't want is the word written over there that is chaitra thats change acoording to month.

Comment: but why its written like this in hindi or i don't know what language is this i want it in english that all.

Comment: @user75758 I've edited my answer

Comment: This has moved to "Dock & Menu Bar"